# Add CSS to Active class

Tags: css

This might be an easy go for the designers but I'm finding it hard to apply a CSS styling to it.

```
<li id="tab2" class="labelRow active"><a href="/name/lbl1#tabs-2"><span>Some Text</span></a></li>
```

Pls tell me the CSS class for it to apply style when it is having active class.

Comment: what css you need in li

Answer (score 2):

To apply a style to the whole li:

```
.labelRow.active {
  /* your styles*/
}
```

for just the span:

```
.labelRow.active span {
  /* your styles*/
}
```

note the lack of space between .labelRow and .active.

Comment: What styling do you want to add?

Comment: just want to give background color, though .labelRow.active span {
  /* your styles*/
} worked but it gives background to the text, not the entire tab.

Comment: to apply a style to the whole <li> use the first example - [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8fR8/).  Have you checked the styling using any sort of developer tools?  Is there any css overriding what you have done?

Comment: yes checking in fire bug, i guess there is some override which i need to check

Answer (score 0):

This is the selector you would use.

```
.labelRow.active {
  /* styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the `.labelRow.active{}` try `li .active{}`